# Java encrypted chat server file transfer

Tags: sockets, encryption, file-transfer

i'm working on a chat server application that transfers data and files using AES encryption. I'm using **DataOutputStream** and **DataInputStream** to send and receive data as well as files.  What i'm doing is to read the data or the file encrypt it, and write it on the stream in byte form. Approach is working good for text and textual files but not good enough for other types of files. Please suggest something to resolve this.

**Sender code**

```
    size = fin.read(b);
    byte encrypted[] = new byte[4 * 1024 * 1024];
    System.arraycopy(encrypted, 0, message, 128, encrypted.length);
    System.out.println(message.length + " " + encrypted.length);
    dout.write(message, 0, encrypted.length + 128);
    dout.flush();
```

**Receiver Code**

```
   message = Client.decrypt(key, b, length);
   FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("./" + fileName);
   fout.write(message.getBytes());
   fout.flush();
   fout.close();
```

**Question Resolved** i was returning the decrypted data as String which was suppressing non readable characters. writing the bytes without non-readable ones was making the file corrupt. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Do other file types get corrupted? or why you say "not good enough for other types" ?

Comment: the files gets corrupted..tried for docx and pdf
bad padding exception is also thrown :/

Comment: I'll need to see more code. From before `size = fin.read(b)` please.

Comment: in that code i had written another 128 bytes that contains senders info and the digest of the message i think the problem is at receiver's end

Comment: the problem is resolved. i was returning String from my decrypt method. i was using getBytes() method while writing it o the file. This depreciated the non-readable characters of the decrypted bytes. To resolve this i returned byte array from the decrypt method and wrote that directly into the file.